# Disabling writing dump files to efivars

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi

Recently I noticed an issue where both of my machines (ThinkPad X230 and W530) independently started running out of NVRAM which stores UEFI boot variables. This prevents them from booting. Fortunately, I managed to boot the OS (Ubuntu 20.04.1 on both) after switching to Legacy boot mode, but this is no fix.

Upon further inspection, it turns out that after every boot, there are numerous "dump-type0" variables created in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. While displaying the contents of "normal" variables using `cat` clearly shows some contents (garbled of course, because this is binary data), `cat`-ting the `dump` variables shows nothing - they seem completely empty, yet take lots of space. These dump variables typically have long names such as `dump-type0-11-1-1643821377-C-cfc8fc79-be2e-4ddc-97f0-9f98bfe298a0`.

I started digging further and searched for parts of these variables' names in journalctl. I found out that these are written to efivars by pstore, evidenced by logs such as this one:

```
Feb 03 10:37:35 slazien-thinkpad-x230 systemd-pstore[1367]: PStore dmesg-efi-164382137702001 moved to /var/lib/systemd/pstore/164382137/dmesg-efi-164382137702001
```

As I understand, it's systemd-pstore which is responsible for moving kernel dumps from `/sys/fs/pstore` to `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` (please correct me in case I'm wrong). Hence I tried disabling pstore processing by setting `Storage=none` in [pstore.conf(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pstore.conf.html#). While this got rid of the aforementioned journalctl logs, the (empty?) dump files are still being written.

For reference, systemd-pstore is running fine:

```
systemctl status systemd-pstore.service
● systemd-pstore.service - Platform Persistent Storage Archival
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-02-03 11:03:13 EST; 2h 13min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-pstore(8)
   Main PID: 1287 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 18853)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-pstore.service

Feb 03 11:03:13 slazien-thinkpad-x230 systemd[1]: Starting Platform Persistent Storage Archival...
Feb 03 11:03:13 slazien-thinkpad-x230 systemd[1]: Finished Platform Persistent Storage Archival.
```

**For now, I would simply want to disable writing of these `dump` efivars while I troubleshoot the root cause. How can I do that?**

**EDIT:** After some detective work I [found out the root cause](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989384). A good overview is provided in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/roadkell/9e98db6656e28fbbf1bf51082040f67f).

Comment: No, the pstore backend *is* efivars. The service is responsible for moving stuff *out* of pstore (and therefore out of efivars) into a regular FS.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent `pstore` from using EFI storage backend, try adding a kernel boot option `efi_pstore.pstore_disable=1` (though I can't check it myself at the moment).

It seems like NVRAM overflow is a rare issue which only affects some laptop models (including ThinkPads xx30), but not the others. If I understand it correctly, some systems have either a poorly implemented EFI firmware, or a too restricted NVRAM space, which, in combination with `pstore` behavior, can lead to overflow.

An early mention of the issue can be found [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=919485). Some more (but still scarce) information: [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/70140) and [here](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/470715/). Still, more digging is needed to uncover the whole picture.

P.S. It is ironic that some non-critical bug in an outdated kernel module can become deadly due to a debugging mechanism trying too hard to preserve kernel dumps.