# Error: The Non-Volatile Variable Storage is About Full: Which efivars can I delete

Tags: ubuntu, acpi

With my thinkpad W530 and ubuntu 21.10 I recently got the problem that the machine didn't boot with the error message:

```
Error: The Non-Volatile Variable Storage is About Full
```

After trying to reboot several times and removing boot entries in the BIOS, I managed, to start again. Then I did some research and found out that it may have to do with a  described [here](https://gist.github.com/roadkell/9e98db6656e28fbbf1bf51082040f67f). Then I upgraded acpi-call-dkms to version 1.2.2 via the tlp ppa as indicated in the link.

As next step I wanted to delete the `*dumb*` efivars, but I didn't find such ones.

So I want to ask, which of my efivars are safe to delete, such that after deletion the error shouldn't occur again.

Here is the output of: `sudo ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/`

```
AcpiGlobalVariable-af9ffd67-ec10-488a-9dfc-6cbf5ee22c2e    LBOP000A-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
AmtSetup-4b9f56be-f68e-4bbc-9bab-cdf600f52d30          LBOP000B-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP000C-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP000D-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0002-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP000E-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0003-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP000F-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0004-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0010-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0005-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0011-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0006-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0012-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0007-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0013-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0008-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0014-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0009-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0015-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot000A-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0016-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot000B-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0017-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot000C-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LBOP0018-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot000D-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoConfig-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot000E-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoFlashScratch1-67c3208e-4fcb-498f-9729-0760bb4109a7
Boot000F-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoHiddenSetting-1827cfc7-4e61-4273-b796-d35f4b0c88fc
Boot0010-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoPciResource-ec0cf62f-0742-4c78-a738-8d66158969d4
Boot0011-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoScratchData-67c3208e-4fcb-498f-9729-0760bb4109a7
Boot0012-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoSecurityConfig-a2c1808f-0d4f-4cc9-a619-d1e641d39d49
Boot0013-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoSystemConfig-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0014-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoThermalShutdown-943d1460-da6e-499a-af6d-4593b12bc4d7
Boot0015-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LenovoWolInfo-0af4027f-9b58-41c0-b62f-cd3a1cef54ee
Boot0016-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LKOP0000-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0017-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LKOP0001-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0018-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LKOP0002-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Boot0019-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LKOP0003-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
BootCurrent-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c       LKOP0004-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
BootOptionSupport-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c     LKOP0005-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
BootOrder-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c         LKOP0006-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
BootOrderDefault-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c      LKOP0007-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
Con-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           LocalSecurityVars-47355e9f-0857-45e1-8a6f-a4f5eda89a77
ConInDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c          LWO-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65
ConOut-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c        MailBoxQ-67c3208e-4fcb-498f-9729-0760bb4109a7
ConOutDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c         MeBiosExtensionSetup-1bad711c-d451-4241-b1f3-8537812e0c70
ConsoleLock-368cda0d-cf31-4b9b-8cf6-e7d1bfff157e       MemoryOverwriteRequestControl-e20939be-32d4-41be-a150-897f85d49829
CpuPpiSetupVar-d1b99f1a-084b-49c3-b88e-378abefa118b    MemoryTypeInformation-4c19049f-4137-4dd3-9c10-8b97a83ffdfa
CpuProtocolSetupVar-7d4adce1-930d-40c7-9cd2-6d2148413dc7   MemoryTypeInformationBackup-4c19049f-4137-4dd3-9c10-8b97a83ffdfa
db-d719b2cb-3d3a-4596-a3bc-dad00e67656f            MokListRT-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
dbx-d719b2cb-3d3a-4596-a3bc-dad00e67656f           MokListXRT-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
DIAGSPLSHSCRN-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c     MTC-eb704011-1402-11d3-8e77-00a0c969723b
DptfProtocolSetupVar-1054354b-b543-4dfe-558b-a7ad6351c9d8  OpromDevicePath-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
ErrOutDev-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c         OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
HDDPWD-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c        OsIndicationsSupported-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
iFfsData-f9f0b131-f346-4f16-80dd-f941072b3a7d          PbaStatusVar-0ec1a7f5-4904-40a0-8eab-4bcc4666da45
KEK-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           PchProtocolSetupVar-04bd8413-15f9-43f3-9675-4618e03240e3
Key0000-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           PK-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Key0001-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           PlatformLang-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Key0002-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           PlatformLangCodes-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Key0003-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           ProtectedBootOptions-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
Key0004-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           PwdStatusVar-3e72b3ad-2b91-424a-ad73-c3270e91ed88
Key0005-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           SaProtocolSetupVar-34f73d4d-963e-4c65-b3b3-515e720175d6
Key0006-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           SbatLevelRT-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
Key0007-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c           SctHotkey-4650c401-93f1-4aeb-b87d-c8204c047dec
LastBootCurrent-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c       SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LBC-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65           Setup-4dfbbaab-1392-4fde-abb8-c41cc5ad7d5d
LBL-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65           SetupHotKey-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LBOL-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          SetupMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LBOP0000-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          SimpleBootFlag-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LBOP0001-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          SMBIOSELOG000-c3eeae98-23bf-412b-ab60-efcbb48e1534
LBOP0002-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          SMBIOSELOGNUMBER-c3eeae98-23bf-412b-ab60-efcbb48e1534
LBOP0003-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          SMBIOSMEMSIZE-c3eeae98-23bf-412b-ab60-efcbb48e1534
LBOP0004-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          System-e947fcf9-dd01-4965-b808-32a7b6815657
LBOP0005-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          TcgSetup-753ab903-444c-41f8-a235-569e8341147e
LBOP0006-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          TdtSetup-810b8b03-2e42-485c-bc93-c35c748e666c
LBOP0007-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          Timeout-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
LBOP0008-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          TpmAcpiData-6403753b-abde-4da2-aa11-6983ef2a7a69
LBOP0009-2a4dc6b7-41f5-45dd-b46f-2dd334c1cf65          TpmSaveState-5e724c0c-5c03-4543-bcb6-c1e23de24136
```

Is there a way to find out the size of the "Non-Volatile Variable Storage" and to see how much of it is used?

My kernel version is `5.13.0-52-generic #59-Ubuntu`.

`/sys/fs/pstore` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the same as this [answer on superuser.se](https://superuser.com/a/1081559/1288835).

To solve it, you can:

- Delete the files responsible for that errors, which are present at `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/dump-*`. They are also present at `/sys/firmware/efi/vars/dump*` although, it [doesn't seem to matter which directories you delete those dump files from, as they represent the same information](https://superuser.com/a/1707258/1288835).
- Prevent it from happening in the future, use `efi_pstore.pstore_disable=1` as kernel options, as mentioned on [this unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689314/409852).

To debug/find the cause of that happening, since it seems like this can happen in cases where there kernel oops, ([example here](https://superuser.com/a/1683089/1288835)) because of an outdated kernel module or some other things, you can take 3 snapshots of the dump files, as mentioned on [this chat entry and the post linked above](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29943291#29943291) to see where the problem lies.

Additionally, you can also remove existing and unneeded kernel modules, and maybe try to switch/remove existing kernel options, to see if it change anything.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, there are no `dumb*` files in my case. So which other files are safe to remove?

Comment: right, my bad :) can you do a `ls` inside `/sys/fs/pstore` to see what's inside? @student

Comment: `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `/sys/fs/pstore` is empty (copy and past mistake...).

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: I thought there would be something there but it doesn't seem to be. I'll be honest with you, I don't know what could be the problem here, as I run out of suggestions to fix it. I guess you could reinstall ubuntu and install the updated tlp package to see if it happens again. @student

Comment: Don't know if it could help, but there also this post I found that gives more details: https://thinkpad--forum-de.translate.goog/threads/erledigt-x230-nvram-voll-%E2%80%93-wie-bereinigen.231596/?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp (it was in german so had to translate it) @student

Comment: feel free to tell me if something worked or not :) @student

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to restart my laptop currently since I need it for work and I am afraid that it will not able to boot anymore. So I am waiting for a definitive answer to my original question...

Comment: @student I see. To be honest with you, based on a couple of posts and forums with similar problems as you (also on a ThinkPad I might add) it seems like there is no definite answer since "it depends". The only way for it to be a definite answer would be if 1. someone who solved or documented the exact problem on the same computer as you posted it, 2. you try the different "clues" I mention, but that requires that you reboot...

Comment: (count) some people managed to fix it seems, but because they tried so many ways to fix it, they can't easily reproduce how they fixed it, and thus don't know what fixed it. At the very least, we know it's at least mostly thinkpads that are mentioned with that problem.

Comment: Yes that might be true. That's why my question was not directly how to solve the problem, but I wanted to know which efi variables are safe do delete (I don't know anything about them) and how to see the size and percentage used of the Non-Volatile Variable Storage.

Comment: yeah, that's understandable :) hopefully, me or someone else finds a way to do that eventually.